# how to pick randome number from the number list

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, random

I need to choose one number randomly from the list of bigint in sql server 2008.
the number list is not continue

For example : The number list may be like this

1578
1579
1580
1587
1589
1590
1595
1603

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: Is the number list in its own table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had success with ordering the top 1 result of a select by newid():

```
select top 1 WhateverId from YourTable order by newid();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply
But i want to user this statement in function, but i cant because of newid(), and my select statement contain the where clause with the variable so i cant create view for this select statement. or cant create stored procedure...cause of SP not call from the function

Answer (score 2):

[Selecting Rows Randomly from a Large Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx)

```
SELECT TOP 1 BigIntColumn FROM Table1
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Note that this solution does _not_ scale well to large tables, as implied by the title of the referenced article.  The article goes on to describe _better_ ways to do this, if your table is large.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers do not scale well to large tables.

This one does, and is available from SQL2005 onwards.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM <table_name> TABLESAMPLE (10 PERCENT)
```

From "further down" in [Selecting Rows Randomly from a Large Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx):

> Often, when questions about how to select random rows are asked in
>   discussion groups, the NEWID query is proposed; it is simple and works
>   very well for small tables. However, the NEWID query has a big
>   drawback when you use it for large tables. The ORDER BY clause causes
>   all of the rows in the table to be copied into the tempdb database,
>   where they are sorted. This causes two problems:
>
> The sorting operation usually has a high cost associated with it.
>   Sorting can use a lot of disk I/O and can run for a long time. In the
>   worst-case scenario, tempdb can run out of space. In the best-case
>   scenario, tempdb can take up a large amount of disk space that never
>   will be reclaimed without a manual shrink command. What you need is a
>   way to select rows randomly that will not use tempdb and will not get
>   much slower as the table gets larger.